# What are the signs of Divine love as enunciated by different Rishis in Narada Bhakti Sutras?

Tags: rishi, bhakti, narada, love, narada-bhakti-sutra

What are the signs of *Bhakti* as enunciated by different Rishis in Narada Bhakti Sutras?

Narada Muni mentions Rishi Parashara, Rishi Garga and Rishi Shandilya in this text. What are the viewpoints of these Rishis on Bhakti?

Comment: Your question was flagged as "low-quality because of its length and content." But to me it appears as a very broad question. Maybe you should ask a specific question or at least state what you know already and what more you want to know. Also remember that a question that shows no research effort can get downvotes ;)

Comment: @sv. That is not a constructive comment. It is specific enough as the purview is limited to Narada Bhakti Sutras. It gets more specific as it is asking only about the 'signs of Divine love' in this purview. Regarding research, I have gone through the whole text multiple number of times, I am not sure what kind of research you are looking for.

Comment: The question must have been flagged as low quality as it was a single line question, I will see if I can edit that.

Comment: Done :) .......

Comment: Yes, people generally view single line questions as no research effort had been made. I thought too broad as in 'What dharma does Krishna teach by way of Mahabharata?' - without giving any background about OP's knowledge about Mahabharata. For such questions Wikipedia might help.

Comment: @sv. Ya, I have edited the question now, it turned out to be a constructive comment after all :)

Answer (score 1):

As is considered a tradition, Narada Muni first describes the viewpoints of various other Rishis. After that, he presents his own viewpoint.

> तल्लक्षणानि वाच्यन्ते नानामतभेदात्   ।।            १५

Different rishis, different traditions have spoken about this divine love and its characteristics. But they are all different - different perceptions. The Truth is the same but they saw different characteristics.

> पूजादिष्वनुराग इति पाराशर्यः   ।।             १६

*Rishi Parashara*, one of the pioneers of the Vedic tradition, said, “A deep interest in *Pooja* is a sign of Divine Love.” ‘Poo’ means fullness; ‘Ja’ means that which is born out of fullness. When you are so full and you are so grateful, what you do from that state of mind, of existence, is Pooja.”

> कथादिष्विति गर्गः   ।।         १७

*Rishi Garga* said Katha, means story - talking about the glory of divine. Listening and talking about it.

> आत्मरत्यविरोधेनेति शाण्डिल्यः   ।।     १८

*Rishi Shandilya* says a characteristic of (divine) love is rejoicing in the *Self* without any conflict.

> नारदस्तु तदर्पिताखिलाचारता तद्विस्मरणे परमव्याकुलतेति   ।।   १९

Having enunciated what other Rishis say, now *Narada* comes to his own way of looking at Divine Love. He says, "But my opinion is *tadarpitakhilacharita*" - *offering all my actions, all my attitudes, all my tendencies to the Divine*. And becoming extremely uncomfortable when one forgets divine, is the real characteristic of Divine love.”

> अस्त्येवमेवम्   ।।    २०
>
> यथा व्रजगोपिकानाम्    ।।    २१

It is like that. Like it happened to the *Gopis of Vrindavan*. Every move they made was for the Divine, their mind, their soul was all immersed in *Lord Krishna*. How they were utterly in dismay, when, even for a moment, they forgot their beloved.

Referenced from [this](http://www.artoflivinguniverse.org/2012/11/narad-bhakti-sutras-sutra-15.html) commentary on the Narada Bhakti Sutras (Shlokas 15-21)